# Accessing data between two functional components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to share some data between two functional components.I have two components : Burger.js & Order.js

State is defined in Burger.js using useState() and i wanted to pass some values (that are in the state) to Order.js.

Code is somewhat like this:

Burger.js =>

```
import Order from './components/order.js';

 const [stateValues, setStateValues] = useState({
    salad: 0,
    chicken: 0,
    cheese: 0,
    tomato: 0,
  });

.
.
.
. /* Code in between */
.
.
<Order orders = {stateValues} />   

.
.
.
.
.
```

Order.js =>

```
.
.
.
const Order = (props) => {

return(
    <div ClassName="xyz">

    const {salad,chicken,cheese,tomato} = props.orders;   

// NOT WORKING. Error Showing up: salad,chicken,cheese,tomato are not defined

    const {salad} = props.orders.salad;    

// THIS IS ALSO NOT WORKING. Error Showing up : 'salad' is not defined
```

I am not able to figure it out what's the problem is there in sharing data through props (both burger.js and order.js are functional components)

Comment: what does the console.log(props.orders) output say inside Order component ?

Comment: what is `props.orders`

Comment: Hey. its console.log(props.orders) outputting undefined.

Comment: Then there must be some problem in your Burger.js file. can you share the full code of Burger.js ?

Comment: @yoel in props.orders i want to access the stateValues that are in burger.js

Comment: @MohammadFaisal how and where to share ?

Comment: edit your post and add that code

Comment: @MohammadFaisal plz see here : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rT8HG6Hymj/

Comment: didn't find any problem with your code. here is a sandbox of your code which works perfectly 

https://codesandbox.io/s/burder-orrder-dqbbc?file=/src/Burger.js

Comment: @MohammadFaisal . It's working fine on my system as well. But thing is when i want to share data to order.js then it's giving error that i mentioned.

Comment: i console logged the data in Order.js file . there the log is not undefined as you mentioned

Comment: @MohammadFaisal https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hrgzPTfkvz/ . here is the link to order.js . it's giving undefiend. plz check

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Hey. In burger.js i replaced < Order orders> with <Order burgerData={stateValues} /> and when i console.log it in order.js it's now showing the state, but when i const {(salad, chicken, cheese, tomato)} = props.burgerData;
its again showing salad,chicken,cheese,tomato are undefined.

Comment: can you update your question. with updated code?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal can i message you somewhere privately ? i need to ask multiple things.

Comment: live:.cid.e806c8aa22a92df8.  its my skype id